# Cannot send html mail content

Tags: email, coldfusion

```
<cfhttp url = "https://api.elasticemail.com/mailer/send?username=myusername&api_key=myapi-key&from=#attributes.from#&from_name=#attributes.from#&to=#attributes.to#&subject=#attributes.subject#&body_html=#attributes.content#&reply_to=#attributes.replyto#"
    method = "POST"
    result="mailResult">
</cfhttp>
```

I am using the above web service for sending emails. When trying to send a large email with HTML content, nothing is being received through the mail. When sending a simple email with HTML content (without any style or background color) it will work correctly. Is there a size limit or any other condition that exists when sending mail? Why is the email not being sent?

Comment: How large is the email content that fails?  You might need to check with the provider to see what limitations they have set on sending email through them.

Answer (score 5):

You have the content (html body) of your email as part of your query string: `&body_html=#attributes.content#`. There is a limit for maximum length of a URL.

Try to find out from the documentation of your mail provider API if you can send the content of the email in the body of your POST request using

```
<cfhttpparam name="body_html" type="formfield" value="#attributes.content#">
```